# How to bind click event of button into PartialView (MVC)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I make a page in asp.net MVC .In this page exist a View and a PartialView.I put button into partialview and write **Countinue**  function into View.

button:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning center-block btn-large" id="Continue" onclick="Continue(this);">Continue</button>
```

js:

```
 var Continue=function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($('#FieldsetCharterFlightsReturn article').size() < 1) {
                if (validateDeparturef(e)) {
                    $("#CharterFlightsForm").submit();
                }

            }
                        if ($('#FieldsetCharterFlightsReturn article').size() > 0) {
                if (validateDeparturef(e) && validateArrivalf(e)) {
                    $("#CharterFlightsForm").submit();
                }
            }
        };
```

Now When i click on the button get this error:

> TypeError: Continue is not a function

What is right way to bind event of elements into PartialView?

Comment: Have your properly included the Continue function definition in the page ? Also you are passing `this` which will be the button and it will not have a method called `preventDefault()`

Comment: Yes.I can delete e.preventDefault()

Comment: Is it in the same view ? or an external js file ? can you put a `console.log("This function exist");` just above your function definition, run your page and verify that message appear in the browser console.

Comment: I wrote  java script codes into script tag into view.

Comment: Try one like `function Continue()` also you need to pass `event` like `onclick="Continue(event);"`

Comment: I test this way but don't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following pattern:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning center-block btn-large" id="Continue" onclick="module.Continue(event);">Continue</button>

(function($, module) {

    module.Continue=function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#FieldsetCharterFlightsReturn article').size() < 1) {
            if (validateDeparturef(e)) {
                $("#CharterFlightsForm").submit();
            }

        }
        if ($('#FieldsetCharterFlightsReturn article').size() > 0) {
            if (validateDeparturef(e) && validateArrivalf(e)) {
                $("#CharterFlightsForm").submit();
            }
        }
    };

}(jQuery, module= window.module|| {}));
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) bind event using it instead of ugly-inline click handler.

```
 $(function(){
    $('#Continue').on('click', Continue);
 })
```

OR, Using Event delegation

```
 $(document).on('click', '#Continue', Continue);
```

And remove inline `onclick="Continue(event);"` handler

Comment: OK.If i don't use ajax for get partialveiw This works currently. Hove ever I found a another way that replace button tag with a tag and delete preventDefault() function.In this way I can use inline code and this work always. Thanks a lot  :)